# Is sprintf( '%d', $tainted ) in an SQL query a vulnerability?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, validation

I do know of parametrized queries, but I've got a couple of old sites where I've used this method for cleaning user input:

```
<?
mysql_query( sprintf( 'SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE id = %d', $tainted ) );
?>
```

Note that there are no quotes around `%d`. Is there any value for `$tainted` that could cause such queries to have unexpected results? It's easy to give syntax errors, but I don't care too much about that.

I've used the same method for similar UPDATE and DELETE queries. Should I bother going back and fixing all old queries, or is there no vulnerability here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not a vulnerability.

But it is a *potential* vulnerability: if some maintenance programmer decides to perform a small change and forgets that the variable may be tainted, or if the variable's data type is changed from integer to string (and the specifier to `%s`) down the road -- then there will be trouble.

It's better to simply not go there to begin with (but from a practical point of view, it's also not apparent if beefing up the defenses of this legacy code is worth it).

Comment: Thanks. I worried because there could be weird byte concoctions that PHP-sprintf considers digits.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, using sprintf in the manner which you presented, should avoid any sql injection, because any non-int values being cast as decimal via %d will simply take on a value of 0:

```
$ -> php -r "echo sprintf('update table where id = %d', 'drop databases');"
update table where id = 0
```

However I would be remiss if I did not attempt to persuade you to use the [PDO](http://us.php.net/pdo) API, and more specifically, [prepared statements](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). I believe the [mysqli](http://us.php.net/mysqli) API also has prepared statements, but I have never used them, only ever used PDO prepare, or an ORM such as Doctrine or Propel.

Answer (score 1):

It appears safe enough as an input, but it's certainly not advisable from a user experience point-of-view, since you won't be able to provide the user with details if the input doesn't match the parameters needed if the id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it shouldn't be vulnerable, because `sprintf()` won't insert the variable if it isn't numeric.

However, that doesn't mean it's right. It may still result in errors that could break your code.

Regardless of whether this is vulnerable or not, I would strongly recommend switching away from the `mysql_xx()` functions entirely.

The old MySQL library has been deprecated (see the notes on [the PHP manual pages](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)), and it is recommended to switch to either PDO or `mysqli_xx` libraries.

Both the PDO and MySQL come with a feature called Prepared Queries, which does exactly what you're trying to achieve here, and is a far better solution than `sprintf()` for this kind of thing. Removes the need to escape all your variables for SQL too.

Hope that helps.